# How to construct a certain derived class by calling the base class constructor with a certain argument

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism, derived-class

So I want to know if its possible to create a certain derived class by constructing the base class with a certain argument. For example:

lets say;

```
class Base
{
    Base::Base(char derived_selector){...};
}
```

```
class DerivedA: public Base
{
   char id_;
   DerivedA::DerivedA(char id):id_(id){};
}

class DerivedB: public Base
{
   int id_;
   DerivedB::DerivedB(int id):id_(id){};
}
```

Now the reason for inheritance from base here is not clear but since its an example I think it should be fine to understand the realtionship here.

What I want to achieve is when I call

```
Base *ptrA  = new Base('A');
Base *ptrB  = new Base('B');
```

The constructor makes the selection of the derived class for me and constructs a DerivedA object for ptrA, and a DerivedB object for ptrB.

I do think there could be some problems like how would the Base constructor know how to set the attributes of the derived class but I feel like it could be achieved somehow. Also if it is indeed possible would this be a good object oriented way or should just decide which one I am making with a simple if else statement when I am going to construct a derived class?

Comment: calling the `Base` constructor contructs a `Base` not a `Derived`. I think you are looking for the factory pattern

Comment: What you are trying to create is called a *factory function*.  The way you are trying to do it won't work in C++.  You could use a free standing factory function like: `Base* MakeBase(char selector) { if (selector == 'A') return new DerivedA(); if (selector == 'B') return new DerivedB(); throw "No soup for you!"; }`

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so this type of behaviour is achieved by using a factory pattern and if I learn that and implement it in my code I can achieve this effect?

Comment: That's a roger, good buddy. SO won't let me just say, "Yes."